# Declare parents aspectj

Tags: spring, aspectj

Firstly I try xml configuration:

```
 <aop:aspect>
        <aop:declare-parents types-matching="DBOperations.ILearningData+" 
                             implement-interface="DBOperations.ISaveResults"
                             delegate-ref="saverExtension"/>
 </aop:aspect>
```

and it works good.

Now I try to make aspectj, which should do the same:

```
public aspect ASaveResults {

public ASaveResults() { }

declare parents : TSaveResults implements ILearningData;
}
```

where TSaveResults is the same as the bean "saverExtension".

I run my code:

```
    ...
@Value("#{learningData}")
protected ILearningData saver;
    ...
    ((ISaveResults)saver).saveResults();
```

and get the error:

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException: sun.proxy.$Proxy12 cannot be cast to DBOperations.ISaveResults

what is the problem with my aspectj?

Also I tried this code unsuccessfully:

```
public aspect ASaveResults {

    public ASaveResults() { }
    
    declare parents : ISaveResults implements ILearningData;
    
    public void saveResults() {
        System.out.println("saver aspect");
    }

}
```

Comment: Have you enabled AOP auto-detection in the spring xml? It looks like the weaving is not happening...

Comment: I've :  <bean class="DBOperations.ASaveResults"/>  and <aop:aspectj-autoproxy/>

Comment: Also aspectj wired good with around and before. So I think my problem is in definition of the aspect ASaveResults

Comment: (updated) declare parents DBOperations.ILearningData+ :  implements DBOperations.ISaveResults; should work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you used there is core aspectj, so if you want to use Spring AOP, but not xml config then this is what you should do (not tested):

```
@Aspect
public class ASaveResults {

   @DeclareParents(value="ISaveResults")
   public static ILearningData interf;

   public void saveResults() {
      System.out.println("saver aspect");
   }
}
```

Comment: Your way I thinkn is good too. But I find the solution wich I want:

Answer (score 1):

```
public aspect ASaveResults {    

public ASaveResults() { }

declare parents : LearningData extends TSaveResults;

}
```

where LearningData and TSaveResults - classes. So now TSaveResults extends LearningData - this was my goal